# Should I hire a company for ID badges or make them in-house?

Tags: work-environment, human-resources

I work in human resources for a company and wondering if I should order our employee badges from a company or make them in-house? I've done quite a bit of research and it seems like outsourcing them could get expensive. Does anybody have experience with this?

Thanks!

Comment: Hello @AlexandraHernandez I am afraid that asking those questions here is off topic, as you are asking us to make a choice for you. In fact, most "Should I" questions are off topic here. Can you rephrase your question, so it has a goal that we can help you with? Welcome to The Workplace :)

Comment: That being said, you should consider your pros and cons of doing them versus outsourcing their production. If it is cheaper, higher quality, faster, etc., those things you have to consider to decide what option is the best for your current needs (i.e.: if you need them ASAP then probably would be better to outsource them, as you probably are not as efficient doing badges as a company specialized in doing so)

Comment: What do you need the employee badge to accomplish? Is it just a name tag so people know who each other's names, or do you need security features? Are you worried about counterfeits? Do you know how to make a badge that does what you need it to do?

Comment: Hi! Thanks so much for the advice and I apologize for not phrasing my question appropriately according to what's "on topic". I need the employee badges for security features. How should I go about obtaining these? I found this site http://www.expressbadging.com/Default.asp and was wondering if perhaps most professionals tend to order from sites like these or from particular shops that maybe I don't know of? Any help is appreciated. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 2):

Depends on what you want out of them?  What are you trying to achieve?

If you just want badges with pictures on them so that everyone knows everyone else's name, but you're not concerned about physical security, go for it and make them in house.  A good quality plastic badge printer is likely to be pretty cheap, and you're just taking a digital picture and printing it on a badge.

OTOH - most of the places I work use id badges for much more than assisting everyone in knowing each other, the badges can unlock doors, get people by human guards, and might even denote the right to hear certain private information to have unique privileges based on job function.  Spoofing them would have serious consquences for the company.  At that point, the technology involved may be a lot more expensive (even in-house) than you think - you want audit logging of electronic access, badges that are compatible with door card readers, a way of canceling badges that are lost, stolen or issued to employees who have left the company, etc.  You'll want to think out what your business hours access is and how it differs from your off-hours access...

At that point, which option is cheap/easy really deserves some analysis with the perspective that you don't want to issue these badges just once, it's an ongoing system.